# translate curl to cfx_http5

Tags: curl, coldfusion

Please help in translating this curl command to cfx_http5 command

```
HTTP method: PUT
URL: http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/partners/{username}/ads/{ext-reference-id}
Sample command:

curl --digest -u{username}:{password} -v -X PUT -H 'Expect: ' -H 'Content-type: application/xml' -d @- http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/partners/{username}/ads/{ext-reference-id} < ad.xml
[Note: - The "ext-reference-id"" is the unique identifier of the ad and should be used for updating and deleting the ad.]

<CFX_HTTP5 username="myusername" password="mypassword" URL="http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/partners/{username}/ads/{ext-reference-id}" OUT="theresponse" METHOD="PUT">
```

Comment: cfhttp doesn't allow digest authentication that's why we use cfx_http5

Comment: I've not a clue about using the CFX_HTTP5 tag, however this person appears to have shared your problem and worked around by hitting java - http://www.terrenceryan.com/blog/post.cfm/digest-authentication-in-coldfusion

Comment: @simon The CFX_HTTP5 solves the digest authentication. My problem is making that curl command work with the cfx_http5.

Comment: This one works in ebay classifieds:
    <CFX_HTTP5 SCHEMES="8" user="#user#" pass="#pass#" METHOD="get"
    URL="#d_url#" OUT="varRESULT" HEADERS="Content-Type: text/xml" HEADERS1="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >

which has a curl equivalent:

curl --digest -u{username}:{password}
 [http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/categories](http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/categories)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually do the digest auth instead of using http5.  Could probably use some tweaking, and add in additional cfhttpparam lines for the extra headers you need:

```
<!--- dummy request to get nonce and domain. --->
<cfhttp url="http://#URLroot#/#RestOfUrl#" method="POST" >
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="">
</cfhttp>
<cfset noncestart = find('nonce="',cfhttp.Header)+7>
<cfset nonceend = find('"',cfhttp.Header,noncestart)>
<cfset nonce = mid(cfhttp.header,noncestart,nonceend-noncestart)>
<cfset Realmstart = find('realm="',cfhttp.Header)+7>
<cfset Realmend = find('"',cfhttp.Header,Realmstart)>
<cfset Realm = mid(cfhttp.header,noncestart,nonceend-noncestart)>
<cfset Hash1 = lcase(Hash("#user#:#Realm#:#pass#","MD5"))>
<cfset Hash2 = lcase(Hash("POST:/#RestOfUrl#", "MD5"))>
<cfset Response = lCase(Hash("#Hash1#:#Nonce#:#Hash2#", "MD5"))>
<cfset Auth = 'Digest username="#user#", realm="#Realm#", nonce="#nonce#", uri="/#RestOfUrl#", response="#Response#"'>
<!--- Real request using Auth in Header. --->
<cfhttp url="http://#URLroot#/#RestOfUrl#" method="POST">
<cfhttpparam name="Authorization"   type="header" value="#Auth#">
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="#postValue#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse I will try it out and let you know if it works. My real problem is translating the cUrl command.